# regex search matches not using group

Tags: c++, regex, boost

Have the following code:

```
boost::regex CriticalHit("<c=#f12d2d>(.+)</c>", boost::regex::icase);
```

idea is to match everything in

```
else if (boost::regex_search(text, damage, CriticalHit)) {
    for (int i = 0; i < damage.size(); i++) {
        HL_LOG_ERR("%s\n", damage[i]);
    }
}
```

this will output varying strings starting at the `<c=#...` part. `damage[0]` gives the whole string, `damage[1]` gives starting at the capture group and then the rest of the string.

The whole string looks like "You critically hit for `<c=#399999>5,992</c>`"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: We don't know what you're trying to match... that's the first thing wrong.

Comment: sorry, i'm trying to match the 5992. lll edit

Comment: SO was removing my formatting

Comment: using `.+?` or `.*?` didnt make a difference. also tried using match[0].first and match[0].second etc but never get the right result

Comment: i'm wanting to get the `5,992` in the above question. i'm not having any trouble matching all the text around it, but getting the `5,992` has proven troublesome. i'm really stuck on this.

Comment: These are the results I get when using the above code:

    `00:51:57 ERROR: <c=#f38400>635</c> using [&btsyaaa=].      `                     
`00:51:57 ERROR: 635</c> using [&btsyaaa=].         `

Comment: You need `boost::regex CriticalHit("<c=#[^<]*>([^<]+)</c>", boost::regex::icase);`

Comment: @sk099 what on earth did "btsyaaa" come from now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nobody here knows what `HI_LOG_ERROR` does. Use standard streams and inserters. As a guess, if the `%s` is part of a C-style format string, then you have to convert `damage[i]` to a C-style string. `damage[i]` is a `sub_match` object, which is essentially two iterators. To convert it to a C-style string, first use its conversion operator to get a C++ string, then use `.c_str()` to get a C string:

```
HI_LOG_ERROR("%s\n", std::string(damage[i]).c_str());
```

Comment: This was the solution. I couldn't figure out for the life of me why the capture group wasn't being printed. Banged my head on the desk for what felt like 4-5 hours and just couldn't figure it out so thanks man. `HL_LOG_ERR` just outputs to a console with `printf` style formatting.